# Vue callback via props and "this"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, callback, this, vue-props

Usually,  when you register an event listener on a button in vanilla JS, if you pass a callback function which uses "this" keyword and it is not an arrow function, when that function gets executed, "this" will reference the button element and you have to use .bind() method to overcome that.
But when you pass a callback function like "props", from a parent component to a child component, and you use it there, and that function also uses "this" keyword, why "this" in a child component has a reference to the parent vue instance and not to the child vue instance? Does vue use some binding behind the scene? Can anyone explain? I have this tutorial where I have parent and a child component and a usecase of an prop which is a callback function that uses "this":

```
// Parent component
    <template>
      <div class="component">
        <h1>The User Component</h1>
        <p>I'm an awesome User!</p>
        <button @click="changeName">Change my Name</button>
        <p>Name is {{ name }}</p>
        <p>Age is {{ age }}</p>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <app-user-detail
              :myName="name"
              @nameWasReset="name = $event"
              :resetFn="resetName"
              :userAge="age"
            ></app-user-detail>
          </div>
          <button id="buton">Buton</button>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <app-user-edit :userAge="age" @ageWasEdited="age = $event"></app-user-edit>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import UserDetail from "./UserDetail.vue";
    import UserEdit from "./UserEdit.vue";

    export default {
      data: function() {
        return {
          name: "Max",
          age: 27
        };
      },
      methods: {
        changeName() {
          this.name = "Anna";
        },
        resetName() {
          console.log(this);
          this.name = "Max";
        }
      },
      components: {
        appUserDetail: UserDetail,
        appUserEdit: UserEdit
      },
      mounted() {
        document.getElementById("buton").addEventListener("click", this.resetName);
      }
    };
    </script>

    <style scoped>
    div {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    </style>

// Child component
<template>
  <div class="component">
    <h3>You may view the User Details here</h3>
    <p>Many Details</p>
    <p>User Name: {{ switchName() }}</p>
    <p>User Age: {{ userAge }}</p>
    <button @click="resetName">Reset Name</button>
    <button @click="resetFn()">Reset Name</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { eventBus } from "../main";

export default {
  props: {
    myName: {
      type: String
    },
    resetFn: Function,
    userAge: Number
  },
  methods: {
    switchName() {
      return this.myName
        .split("")
        .reverse()
        .join("");
    },
    resetName() {
      this.myName = "Max";
      this.$emit("nameWasReset", this.myName);
    }
  },
  created() {
    eventBus.$on("ageWasEdited", age => {
      this.userAge = age;
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

All that's done to `props` in Vue is pass them down and attach them to the Child component instance.

**No other kind of binding is performed**, therefore the context (`this`) will still be the parent

I suggest using [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) instead of passing down Function props as in React.

[Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) are more Vue-like (pretty much the convention, as that's what a Vue developer would look for first when having parent-child communication), they will be easier to keep track of and the event's context will be clear from the ground up.